# Find out a strings location (columns) in SQL

Tags: sql

Below is my SQL query to find out, do any of the columns (`Req_ecCode1`, `Req_ecCode2`, `Req_ecCode3`) have the word `“YC”`. Now my concern is there any way that I can know what is the column name does `“YC”` located at?
Hope anyone can help me on this.

```
select *
from SC_Main
where Req_ecCode1 + Req_ecCode2 + Req_ecCode3 like ‘%YC%’
```

Comment: What version of SQL are you using?

Comment: For the base query, use `where a like x or b like y or c like ..` - this allows the SQL engine to be as efficient as a it can be given the current schema. It will also not capture false-positives like `'MAY' + 'CAR' like '%YC%'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tend to concatenate the string names together:

```
select ((case when Req_ecCode1 like '%YC%' then 'Req_ecCode1;' else '' end) +
        (case when Req_ecCode2 like '%YC%' then 'Req_ecCode2;' else '' end) +
        (case when Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%' then 'Req_ecCode3;' else '' end)
       ) as columns_with_yc
from SC_Main
where Req_ecCode1 + Req_ecCode2 + Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%'
```

Note that your `where` conditions isn't really correct.  If one code is `'Y'` and the next `'C'`, then it will evaluate to true.  Presumably, you want:

```
where Req_ecCode1 like '%YC%' or
      Req_ecCode2 like '%YC%' or
      Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%'
```

Or, if you don't want to repeat the pattern, use a delimiter:

```
where Req_ecCode1 + '|' + Req_ecCode2 + '|' + Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%'
```

Comment: Note that this solution would find YC anywhere in the string, even when it is not a standalone word.  How do you know the OP's database version?

Answer (score 4):

You can use a case statement to identify that and use OR in where condition to check for YC,

```
 SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN Req_ecCode1 like '%YC%' then 1 else 0 end as Req_ecCode1,
    CASE WHEN  Req_ecCode2 like '%YC%' then 1 else 0 end as Req_ecCode2,
    CASE WHEN  Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%' then 1 else 0 end as Req_ecCode3,
    FROM SC_Main
    WHERE Req_ecCode1 like '%YC%' OR Req_ecCode2 like '%YC%' OR Req_ecCode3 like '%YC%'
```

Comment: Note that this solution would find `YC` _anywhere_ in the string, even when it is not a standalone word.